# Different between design dialog by mfc in visual studio and when build?

Tags: mfc

This is my first post, hope you will help me as soon as.

Thank alot for read my question.

I design a MFC's dialog in visual studio 2010.

My dialog's size is 500 x 397

In my code, I try to draw a line

dc.MoveTo(0,0)

dc.lineTo(500,397).

But it look like this

(Sorry I dont enough repuration to insert image)
http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2353/erroryq.png

This code must be draw form left-top to right-bottom of dialog
But, it's not happen.

The size of dialog is change :( maybe larger ....
I actually don't know why @_@

Maybe becuz setting of screen in Visual Studio and my Desktop.
Hope you can help me fix that code

Thank alot

Comment: How do you know the size 500 by 397? What does `GetClientRect()` say the size is?

Answer (score 1):

Dialogs are designed in "Dialog Units" which are not the same as pixels.  To convert between the two, try MapDialogRect().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502(v=vs.85).aspx